# Google Apps Script Doc Add-on fails to install

Tags: google-apps-script-addon

After creating an Apps Script Add-on, and following [Publishing an editor add-on](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/how-tos/publishing-editor-addons) instructions, the installation fails.  (The Add-on visibility is "Private, Everyone at ".

1. From the Web Store listing, the install button (labeled "Free") is clicked.
2. A new document is opened, and "Working" is shown briefly
3. An error message is displayed, "Opps Add-on not found. Try again, or check back later."

[image: Error message dialog, "Opps Add-on not found. Try again, or check back later."]

Comment: I'm dealing with this too. The addon publishing process is so buggy and complex, it has given me a headache. Were you able to have any luck with resolving this problem?